# how to correlate the position a value in one list to a name in a different one

Tags: python

I have a 3D list/array and need to find the position of the highest value and use that position to locate a name in the same dimension but a different list

I've tried .index() and iterating through the list as well as max() and I can't think of what else to use

the list is as follows the first set of names corresponds to the numbers below:

```
[[['ellen', 'barnacles', 'vee', 'charlie'], [5, 7, 4, 8]], [['danny', 'craig', 'dave', 'isaac'], [2, 1, 0, 3]]]
```

I need to get the position of the max value (in this instance for the first team) 8 and have it figure out that its associated with 'charlie'

Answer (score 1):

Use combination of `zip` (to pair names and numbers in a sublist) + [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) (with `key` argument as ordering function) functions:

```
max_items = [max(zip(*sub_l), key=lambda x: x[1]) for sub_l in lst]
```

---

```
[('charlie', 8), ('isaac', 3)]
```